# DB2 SQL query to get pairs of the same values in one column and different values in another column within that pairs

Tags: sql, duplicates, db2

Can someone help me write query that shows data as follows:
column AMOUNT has pairs of duplicates and column CASH_CO has differnt values on each pair.

I tired this but it shows no results. I check DB manually and there are such items.

```
SELECT S1.AMOUNT, S1.CASH_CO, S1.ACCOUNT_ID
FROM HI_MTI_O1 S1
INNER JOIN HI_MTI_01 S2
ON (S1.ACCOUNT_ID = S2.ACCOUNT_ID AND S1.AMOUNT = S2.CASH_CO)
WHERE (S1.CASH_CO <> S1.CASH_CO AND S1.AMOUNT = S2.AMOUNT)
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

[image]

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Comment: `S1.CASH_CO <> S1.CASH_CO` is never true.

Comment: Why do you have some join conditions in ON, but others in WHERE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH HI_MTI_O1 (ACCOUNT_ID, AMOUNT, CASH_CO) AS
(
  VALUES 
    ( 1, 100, 'BNP')
  , ( 2, 100, 'DB')
  , ( 3, 200, 'SSG')
  , ( 4, 200, 'SSG')
  , ( 5, 300, 'TRGT')
  , ( 6, 300, 'TRGT')
  , ( 7, 500, 'HSBC')
  , ( 8, 600, 'HSBC')
  , ( 9, 800, 'RO')
  , (10, 800, 'EC')
)
SELECT S.*
FROM HI_MTI_O1 S
JOIN 
(
  SELECT AMOUNT
  FROM HI_MTI_O1
  GROUP BY AMOUNT
  HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT CASH_CO) > 1
) G ON G.AMOUNT = S.AMOUNT
ORDER BY S.ACCOUNT_ID
```

| ACCOUNT_ID | AMOUNT | CASH_CO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | BNP |
| 2 | 100 | DB |
| 9 | 800 | RO |
| 10 | 800 | EC |